# Filter on column family with special character

Tags: java, hbase, hbase-filter

I have a column family that contains "_" character and I want to apply a filter using java on one of the columns associated with this column family. Below is the code that I have written:

```
HTable table = new HTable(config, tableName);
SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("Employee_details"),
                                Bytes.toBytes("organizationid"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
                                new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf(FilterValue))));

scan.setFilter(filter);
ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

Employee_details is the column family and organizationid is the associated column name. When I run this code on the column families which contains "_", filter does not work but it works perfectly fine when column family contains only alphabets. How can I make this filter work.